# Retrofit refresh token authentication

Tags: java, android, retrofit

This is my token access method. I have an api where it has token and expires after 5 mins I got the token but I don't know how to get the new token if it expires after 5 mins and I am using retrofit.

private static String mToken, email = "xxx@gmail.com",password = "1234";

```
public void loginProcess() {
    User user = new User(email,password);
    Call<Login> call = userClient.login(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                mToken = response.body().getToken();
                Call<ResponseBody> call1 = userClient.user(mToken);//passed the token   
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CountDownTimer` and set it to 5 Minute then in `onFinish` method Call `loginProcess` and call `CountDownTimer` self method  to check your token in each 5 minute

Comment: This is working good but there's a lot of errors in the logcat seems I need to change a little bit.